# (GWT tutorial) StockPriceServiceImpl::getPrices() called 5 times

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm struggling with the StockPriceService example in GWT.  I have managed to get it running and got to step 2 (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) where I implemented a StockPriceServerImpl class.

```
public class StockPriceServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements StockPriceService {
```

It works, i.e. gets called OK, but here's the problem:

I declare a variable in the class like:

```
private ConfigurationLoader confLoader = null;
```

and then in the getPrices() method:

```
if (confLoader == null) {
    System.out.println("----creating a conf loader instance ---");
    confLoader = new ConfigurationLoader("192.168.2.199","8888");
}
```

The problem when I run it is:

The message "----creating a conf loader..." is printed 5 (five) times.... then it apparently runs OK...?

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it turns out this was my mistake. Since the call to getPrices() was asynchronous and sent with just 1s between calls, and the construction of ConfigurationLoader was slower than that, I got 5 calls before ConfigurationLoader was done. It works better now!